# Odoo overriding unlink, why are all values False

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, odoo-14

Im doing the [odoo getting started](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/howtos/rdtraining/13_inheritance.html) tutorial. Im trying to override the unlink method so that I prevent the deletion when a record in a specific state. I couldn't get it to work so I used some breakpoints to inspect the variables. To my suprise the values are all False. I guess this is some default value for undefined variables in odoo, but my record is not undefined.

```
@api.model
def unlink(self, record_id):
    breakpoint() # all values of self are False
    for record in self:
        breakpoint() # I never get here
    breakpoint()
```

I dont understand why everything is False. In other functions(depends, inverse, onchange) that I wrote for this tutorial this never is the case.

And I also can't find a get_by_id function. Does that not exist in odoo?

Comment: If all values of `self` are `False` the recordset is empty and that means your override of that method (here `unlink`) went horribly wrong. You already found out, that the signature of the method matters in this case and probably in all cases for Odoo's ORM methods. And to your second question: you're probably looking for `Model.browse()` which takes a list of IDs and returns a recordset.

Comment: What do you mean with the signature of the method?

Comment: "In computer programming, especially object-oriented programming, a method is commonly identified by its unique method signature, which usually includes the method name, and the number, types and order of its parameters.[2] A method signature is the smallest type of a method." From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature#Method_signature)

Answer (score 2):

try this...,
I think it will help you...

```
def unlink(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.stage == "Your_stage":
            raise UserError(_('You can not delete record in Your_stage stage.'))
        else:
            return super(Your_current_class, self).unlink()
```

Comment: Thank for you help, I did already fix it though. My solution is kinda the same. But why do you add the the api.multi decorator though?

Comment: @api. multi is used when we want to loop on recordsets in this case self is the recordset , the recordset hold one or more record so we need to loop manually to extract record

Comment: Okee, but shouldn't you loop over self then?

Comment: ``@api.multi`` was removed in [Odoo-13.0](https://github.com/OCA/maintainer-tools/wiki/Migration-to-version-13.0#tasks-to-do-in-the-migration), now they are all multi-record by default

Comment: yes, you are right..,

Comment: Except for Odoo 15+ `self.stage == "Your_stage"` could raise `SingletonError`, everytime there is more than one record in `self`.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I just found out that apparently in odoo if I do:

```
def unlink(self): # takes only self
    breakpoint() # I can access the values

@api.model
def unlink(self, record_id): # takes two arguments
    breakpoint() # all values are False
```

I dont know why though